# How to use sudo command in the default guest account?

Tags: security

How can I use sudo command from terminal in the default Ubuntu 12.04 guest account, in order to connect to vpn client and service. (OpenVPN+TrustConnect+Comodo)

I know it has been disable by default(sudo), but I want to use guest account, apparmor, etc, and security feutures of guest account, and still be able to connect to vpn.

Vpn client and service wont star without sudo command.

Comment: Is configuring network-manager to connect to the VPN at boot an option?

Comment: @Jordan Uggla Wow, is the first time I hear about that, I will study that one and give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule to the `sudoers` file that gives the guest account the permission to gain root privileges but only execute the command that starts the VPN, and possibly the command that stops the VPN.

Run `visudo`, and add lines like the following:

```
guest ALL = /usr/sbin/service openvpn start
guest ALL = /usr/sbin/service openvpn stop
```

---

Alternatively, if applicable, you could tie the VPN service to the network interface for general Internet connectivity. For example, if your network interface is `eth0`, add a file in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ]; then
  service openvpn start
fi
```

and in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ]; then
  service openvpn stop
fi
```

If you use OpenVPN and your network interface is configured in [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) rather than via NetworkManager, you can configure an OpenVPN VPN to start there.

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    OPENVPN=trustconnect
```

There may be a way to do this with NM as well but I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

You could use sudo and the `usermod` command from an account that *does* have sudo access to add the `adm` group (for 12.04) to the account. Don't forget to use the `-a` option to add the group rather than replacing the group list.

Comment: Hmm, guest accounts on Ubuntu are created and destroyed on the fly... Each login a different one. Doable changing the template, but not so straightforward....

Comment: That would give the guest account admin powers, which defeats the purpose of a guest account.